# Checking if a value exists in drupal database

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I'm making a form in drupal and want to check if an email already exists in my database.

```
  db_insert('CASL_SUBBED')
    ->fields(array(


      'email' => $form_state['values']['email'],//email
      'ip' => $ip55,//ip
      'substatus' => $subbed,
      'datetime' => $sDate,//date and time
```

That's my code for inserting into the database, but I want to see if the email already exists before I insert this into it. Is there anyway to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do an insert and check if it exists at the same time. Try checking if it exists first and then run the insert if it doesn't like this:

```
    $hasEmail = db_select('CASL_SUBBED', 'n')
        ->fields('n')
        ->condition('email', $form_state['values']['email'],'=')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAssoc();

    if(!$hasEmail) {
        db_insert('CASL_SUBBED')
            ->fields(array(
              'email' => $form_state['values']['email'],//email
              'ip' => $ip55,//ip
              'substatus' => $subbed,
              'datetime' => $sDate,//date and time
        ))
        ->execute();    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. I'm quite new to drupal, so what does that 'n' value stand for? Is it just a placeholder?

Comment: n is the table alias for CASL_SUBBED. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Afields/7

Comment: since I am only calling the alias (n) in the fields() call it will return all the fields from that table.